# Issue updating sabnzbdplus package because of unmet dependency

Tags: 12.04

I trying to do apt-get install, but nomatter what I do (sudo apt-get -f install, sudo apt-get purge sabnzbdplus etc) it just complains about this unmet dependency.

[image: Screenshot of terminal output]

Edit:

```
mads@madsserver:~$ sudo apt-get remove sabnzbdplus-theme-smpl sabnzbdplus
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 sabnzbdplus-theme-classic : Depends: sabnzbdplus (= 0.7.6-0ubuntu1~jcfp1~precise) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
mads@madsserver:~$ sudo apt-get remove sabnzbdplus-theme-classic sabnzbdplus
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 sabnzbdplus-theme-smpl : Depends: sabnzbdplus (= 0.7.6-0ubuntu1~jcfp1~precise) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: It would be preferable if the error was copied and pasted as text. This makes it searchable and easier to read.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key part of the error message is:

```
sabnzbdplus depends on nabnzdbplus-theme-plush (= 0.7.6-0ubuntu1~jcfp1-precise); however:
Version of sabnzbdplus-theme-plush on system is 0.7.7-0ubuntu1~jcfp1-precise.
```

The package `sabnzbdplus` depends on the package `nabnzdbplus-theme-plush` with the specific version number `0.7.6-0ubuntu1~jcfp1-precise`. However, you already have that package installed, just a different version (`0.7.7-0ubuntu1~jcfp1-precise`).

The solution is to uninstall `sabnzdbplus-theme-plush` and similar packages, and try to install `sabnzbdplus` again from scratch:

```
sudo apt-get remove nabnzdbplus-theme-plush sabnzbdplus-theme-smpl sabnzbdplus-theme-classic sabnzbdplus
sudo apt-get install sabnzdbplus
```

Comment: When I try to remove them I jsut get these 2 new ones (See edit) that it depends on, and I cant remove them as they seem to be circular dependent

Comment: @Mech0z: see edit. (To see the history of the answer, click on on the time next to "edited" underneath the question.)